# android - Horizontal Progress bar not updating inside list item

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I am newbie on android programming, now I met a wired thing on it, I created a listActivity, and the layout of list item is like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/offlineItemIcon"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/user_avatar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/offlineItemTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="卷001 2012-08-23 3.0M"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/lightdark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/offlineLoadingbar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="10" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonOfflineItemDownload"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:background="@drawable/xml_button_loadmore"
                android:text="download"
                android:textColor="@color/lightwhite"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/commentDate" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I made a class to wrap the content of this layout, this one -

```
public class OfflineItemView extends LinearLayout {

    Context _context = null;

    public Button buttonDownload = null;
    public ProgressBar loadingProgress = null;
    public TextView title = null;
    public ImageView icon = null;

    public String url = null;
    public String filename = null;

    public OfflineItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        _context = context;
        init();
    }

    public OfflineItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        _context = context;
        init();
    }

    protected void init() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.module_offline_item, this);

        buttonDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOfflineItemDownload);
        buttonDownload.setTag("download");

        loadingProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.offlineLoadingbar);
        loadingProgress.setMax(100);
        loadingProgress.setProgress(0);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.offlineItemTitle);
        icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.offlineItemIcon);
    }

    public void setTitle(String message) {
        if (message != null) {
            title.setText(message);
        } else {
            title.setText("");
        }
    }

    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

        if (bitmap != null) {
            icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    public void setListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    public void setProgress (int i)
    {
        android.util.Log.v ("item", i + "");
        loadingProgress.setProgress(i);
        android.util.Log.v ("item", "current : " + loadingProgress.getProgress());
    }

}
```

The list working pretty good, it display all item without problem, the screenshot of the list item is -

[image]

When the user clicked the button, it will invoke an AsyncTask class to download a file as well as display the progress on item, the download class -

```
public void downloadOffline(String url, String path,
        OfflineItemView progress) {

    DownloadOfflineAsync downloader = new DownloadOfflineAsync(progress);
    downloader.execute(url, path);
}

class DownloadOfflineAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private final WeakReference<OfflineItemView> progressbarReference;

    public DownloadOfflineAsync(OfflineItemView progress) {
        progressbarReference = new WeakReference<OfflineItemView>(progress);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            android.util.Log.v("downloadFile", "Lenght of file: "
                    + lenghtOfFile + ":" + aurl[1]);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(aurl[1]);

            try {
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""
                            + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }


            } finally {

                if (output != null) {
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                }

                if (input != null) {

                    input.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        if (progressbarReference != null) {
            OfflineItemView p = progressbarReference.get();

            //android.util.Log.v ("offline.download", progress[0]);
            p.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

        OfflineItemView p = null;

        if (progressbarReference != null) {
            p = progressbarReference.get();
            p.buttonDownload.setTag("browser");
            p.buttonDownload.setText("browse");
            p.requestLayout();
        }

    }
}
```

And it's working well, the file is downloaded, and progress is notified to onProgressUpdate, also the loading progress bar on item class is working fine, the progress is set correctly (to print on logcat, and all correct), but the problem is the progress bar never update its indicator, so even the progress is updated from 0 to 100 increasingly, the progress bar doesn't change anything to show the progress on its UI, so anyone who can give me some advices are appreciated..

PS:

I move the download function to getView (), and seems it's working great, the progress bar is updating, but in the button event handler is not working, so seems it's list view problem, how to solve this problem, but?

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        rowView = new OfflineItemView(_context);
        JSONObject item = getItem(position);

        try {
            if (item != null) {
                String t = item.getString(Offline.TAG_NAME) + " "
                        + item.getString(Offline.TAG_DATE) + " "
                        + item.getString(Offline.TAG_SIZE);

                rowView.setTitle(t);

                if (listener == null) {
                    listener = new ItemButtonOnClickListener();
                }

                if (item.optBoolean("dir_exists")) {
                    rowView.buttonDownload.setText("browse");
                    rowView.buttonDownload.setTag("browser");
                }

                rowView.setListener(listener);
                rowView.url = item.getString(Offline.TAG_URL);
                rowView.filename = item.getString(Offline.TAG_FILENAME);

                String imageUrl = item.optString(Offline.TAG_ICON);

                if (imageUrl == null || imageUrl.trim().equals("")) {

                } else {

                    String name = item.optString(Offline.TAG_UNZIP_NAME) + "o";
                    if (name != null) {
                        if (DiskCache.getInstance().fileExists("user_" + name,
                                "user")) {
                            android.util.Log.v("offline", name + ":exists");
                            Bitmap bitmap = DiskCache.getInstance().get(
                                    "user_" + name, "user");
                            if (bitmap != null) {
                                rowView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            }
                        } else {

                            // FileDownloader.getInstance().download(imageUrl,
                            // image, name);
                        }

                    }
                }


            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rowView;

    }
```

Comment: I cannot see what is wrong here. I would check that the progress bar reference is the same as the progress bar currently displayed on the screen, and not another one.

Comment: Hi thanks, actually I moved the download function to getView(), and it's updating fine, but inside event handler, it will not update progress bar UI...so...

Comment: Can you post the content of your `getView()` method (before moving the download function)?

Comment: so sorry, I found it's my fault, it was working, just I didn't see it because when I clicked the first button, the progress bar of the first item is not updating, but the sixth one is updating...so far I don't know why...you are right, the code is fine..just my fault. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approaching this in kind of a curious way.  You said you're new to Android, and I can't tell from your comment thread above what your current state of brokenness is.  However, I can tell you you're not following `ListView` best-practices, and that you might run into some strange issues when you scroll down your list.

You should use the `convertView` parameter you're given.  `convertView` is either null, or a `View` which you have previously returned from `getView`.  Since you are only ever returning `OfflineItemView`s, if `convertView != null` it's going to be an instance of `OfflineItemView`, which you can reuse to avoid the overhead of creating a completely new one at draw-time every time a new item is displayed.

Basically:

```
View rowView;
if(convertView == null){
     rowView = convertView;
} else {
     rowView = new OfflineItemView(item);
}
```

Just be careful with logic like this, because the next time you re-use the view the tags will still be there from the last item that occupied it:

```
            if (item.optBoolean("dir_exists")) {
                rowView.buttonDownload.setText("browse");
                rowView.buttonDownload.setTag("browser");
            }
```

I.E., you may need an `else` clause to say `rowView.buttonDownload.setText("");` and nullify the tag in the event that `dir_exists` is false.

Additionally, (assuming you mean to use something like the commented-out `ImageDownloader` code you have in `getView`) if the image doesn't exist in your image cache, you may spawn off multiple downloads of the same image if `getView` is called more than once before the image is actually downloaded.

If you can edit your question to clarify precisely what is broken right now, I can refine this answer to help you further.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. I did check it according to your advice, and fixed some bugs on it, and now it's working. :)